# how to decrease API requests sent from flutter map package?

Tags: flutter, maptiler

'''I am using flutter map with maptiler as a server and requests are way more than it suppose to be. how can I optimize? '''

Comment: Can you include current snippet how you are calling api?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map   this is the package I use, and within 2 days there was sent more than 200 000 requests sent to maptiler

Comment: I would use Timer.periodic but I don't understand this package. Please show a snippet where it call the Api.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.